# Options to view deleted history from Chrome on Linux. No backup

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-chrome, history, recovery

I have seen several questions and links via google search that help in this process; however, they don't work in my case.

1. I am on Linux and many of those links are for Windows/Mac.
2. I don't have a backup.

I have not seen a no-backup solution for Linux. Also, I have both a Linux and Mac, but, the accidental deletions occurred from my Linux machine.

**Technically, I just need the records. If there is another option that allows me to see the history, I am possibly game for that, too.** Especially if it is an easier method.

However, from reading other articles, I assume I need to use forensic software to recover deleted history without any backups.

Answer (score 0):

This question is more about recovery deleted files, but it depends on Chrome encryption and filesystem configuration. It depends on how well the program wipes the data... If you use ext4 try this: https://gist.github.com/ebautistabar/cca12863e6335d08a019f015f53fac4a
I don't recommend to use system until you find solution, because data may be overwritten. Also, visit Chromium project to find info about encryption and other nuances: https://www.chromium.org/

Most likely you cannot do this. There is a security issue and data is properly overwritten, I think so.